QT Designer Crashing when trying to change cursor style on MacOs
I'm trying to create a Qt application using Qt Designer on macOS Sonoma 14.4.1. However, I'm facing a problem: every time I try to change my cursor style or define the frame shape of my frame, the app just crashes.
Here's the summarized error log:
-------------------------------------
Translated Report (Full Report Below)
-------------------------------------

Process:               Designer [2217]
Path:                  /Users/USER/*/Designer.app/Contents/MacOS/Designer
Identifier:            org.qt-project.Designer
Version:               ???
Code Type:             ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        launchd [1]
User ID:               my_user_id

Date/Time:             2024-04-04 21:48:54.0345 +0100
OS Version:            macOS 14.4.1 (23E224)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        my_anonymous_uid


Time Awake Since Boot: 870 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 6 Abort trap: 6
Terminating Process:   Designer [2217]

The rest of the program works just fine, and this problem only occurs when I attempt to change my cursor style or the frame shape.
I've already tried the following:

Update my MacOs to the latest version (Sonoma 14.4.1 now)
Update the dependencies on QT Maintenance Tool (already latest version)
Running QT Designer with root privileges on terminal


Have you tried to completely uninstall and reinstall Qt? The fact that you have a crash when changing cursor style or frame shape seems related to enums, have you tried to change enums of other widget properties?

Thanks, @musicamante! Reinstalling Qt did work!

Why not answer your own question?

A solution that worked for me was completely uninstalling Qt using the Qt Maintenance Tool and then reinstalling it.
Additionally, updating Qt using the same tool also fixed some problems with other widgets, but only uninstalling it completely resolved issues with the cursor style and frame shape.
